# One element array in struct

Tags: arrays, struct, element

Why some struct uses a single element array, such as follows:

```
typedef struct Bitmapset
{
 int nwords;
 uint32 words[1];
} Bitmapset;
```

To make it convenient for latter dynamic allocation?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In a word, yes.

Basically, the C99 way to do it is with an [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member):

```
uint32 words[];
```

Some pre-C99 compilers let you get away with:

```
uint32 words[0];
```

But the way to guarantee it to work across all compilers is:

```
uint32 words[1];
```

And then, no matter how it's declared, you can allocate the object with:

```
Bitmapset *allocate(int n)
{
    Bitmapset *p = malloc(offsetof(Bitmapset, words) + n * sizeof(p->words[0]));
    p->nwords = n;
    return p;
}
```

Though for best results you should use `size_t` instead of `int`.

Comment: Thanks. So will this tricky allocation has a problem for the struct padding thing, say if the passed n is an odd number?

Comment: @Oxdeadbeef - Yes, I suppose. You won't really store an array of them in contiguous memory. If you wanted an array of them you'd probably be better off using `Bitmapset *a[20] = { NULL };` or `Bitmapset **a = malloc(20 * sizeof *a);`.

Comment: The syntax `offsetof(Bitmapset, words[n])` is an extension (which happens to be supported by most compilers). For strict compliance, use `offsetof(Bitmapset, words) + n*sizeof(p->words[0])`.

Comment: @Jed - I didn't know that, though I should have guessed. Fixed.

Comment: @ChrisLutz: Is there anything in the standard that would forbid a compiler from optimizing `p->words[i]` as `p->words[0]`, since the former only has defined behavior in the case where the allocated memory exists for the array element, *and* the subscript is less than the size of the array (i.e. is zero)? I suspect even compilers which might normally optimize single-item array accesses will refrain from doing so if the array is the last item in an indirectly-accessed structure, but is there anything in the standard which would forbid it (or justify code's assumption that compilers won't do it)?

Comment: @supercat - I don't think so, but I'd have to consult the standard, and I don't have a copy of C11 yet. Also I have work to get done, so I'll get back to you on that.

Comment: @ChrisLutz: Was there ever anything in any earlier version of the standard that would forbid a compiler from making such an optimization?

Answer (score 7):

This is usually to allow idiomatic access to variable-sized struct instances.  Considering your example, at runtime, you may have a Bitmapset that is laid out in memory like this:

```
-----------------
| nwords   |  3 |
| words[0] | 10 |
| words[1] | 20 |
| words[2] | 30 |
-----------------
```

So you end up with a runtime-variable number of uint32 "hanging off" the end of your struct, but accessible as if they're defined inline in the struct.  This is basically (ab)using the fact that C does no runtime array-bounds checking to allow you to write code like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myset.nwords; i++) {
  printf("%d\n", myset.words[i]);
}
```

Comment: Abusing indeed. :D