# Why does such a struct contain two array fields containing only one element?

Tags: c, arrays, linux, struct, idioms

**Please Note: This question is not a duplicate of** ( [One element array in struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559558/one-element-array-in-struct) )

The following code is excerpted from the Linux kernel source (version: 3.14)

```
struct files_struct
{
    atomic_t count;
    struct fdtable __rcu *fdt;
    struct fdtable fdtab;

    spinlock_t file_lock ____cacheline_aligned_in_smp;
    int next_fd;
    unsigned long close_on_exec_init[1];
    unsigned long open_fds_init[1];
    struct file __rcu * fd_array[NR_OPEN_DEFAULT];
};
```

I just wonder why `close_on_exec_init` and `open_fds_init` are defined as arrays containing one element, rather than just defined as `unsigned long close_on_exec_init;` and `unsigned long open_fds_init;`.

Comment: also good explanation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390331/why-use-array-size-1-instead-of-pointer)

Comment: It seems like it can't possibly be a hack for flexible arrays since the array members aren't at the end.

Comment: The post given above is different from this question. And the answer does not apply to this question.

Comment: @xmllmx Can you explain how your question is different?

Comment: @Code-Guru, the number of array fields are more than one, and not the last fields.

Comment: [Here is the patch](https://lkml.org/lkml/2006/1/3/500) that introduced this, pretty much. Originally something to do with saving space on embedded platforms... I will leave it to others to figure out the details

Answer (score 6):

These fields are an optimization so Linux doesn't have to perform as many allocations for a typical process that has no more than `BITS_PER_LONG` open file descriptors.

The `close_on_exec_init` field provides the initial storage for `fdt->close_on_exec` when a `files_struct` is allocated.  (See `dup_fd` in `fs/file.c`.)

Each bit of `fdt->close_on_exec` is set if the corresponding file descriptor has the “close-on-exec” flag set.  Thus Linux only needs to allocate additional space for `fdt->close_on_exec` if the process has more open file descriptors than the number of bits in an `unsigned long`.

The `open_fds_init` field serves the same function for the `fdt->open_fds` field.  The `fd_array` field serves the same function for the `fdt->fd` field.  (Note that `fd_array` has a size of `BITS_PER_LONG`.)

The `close_on_exec_init` and `open_fds_init` fields formerly had type `struct embedded_fd_set`, but were changed to bare arrays in [this commit](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/1fd36adcd98c14d2fd97f545293c488775cb2823).  The commit message doesn't explain why the author chose to use one-element arrays instead of bare scalars.  Perhaps the author (David Howells) simply wanted to avoid using the `&` operator.

Answer (score 2):

My best guess: The addresses of these fields are used much more often than their actual values.  In this case, making them size-1 arrays saves typing `&` every time their address is needed, since in C using the name of an array in an expression is in nearly all cases exactly equivalent to taking the address of its first element:

```
int x;
int y[1];

function_that_needs_address_of_int(&x);
function_that_needs_address_of_int(y);
function_that_needs_address_of_int(&y[0]);    // Identical to previous line
```

(As others have pointed out in the comments, it can't be that the fields are being used as a hack for variable-length arrays, since there is more than one and they don't appear at the end of the `struct`.)

**[EDIT:** As pointed out by user3477950, an array name is not always identical to the address of its first element -- in certain contexts, like the argument to `sizeof`, they mean different things.  (That's the only context I can think of for C; in C++, passing an array name as an argument can also enable a template parameter's type to be inferred to be a reference type.)**]**

Comment: "using the name of an array in an expression is exactly equivalent to taking the address of its first element" - no, they are not exactly equivalent (think `sizeof` et al.), it would be better explain that an array name may decay into a pointer to its first element in some contexts.