# Significance of array with only one element

Tags: c, arrays, structure

I have come across an array with only one element. This array is defined inside a structure. Which goes like this:

```
typedef struct abc
{
    int variable1;
    char variable2;
    float array[1];
};
```

I don't understand why this array is required, why can't we define just a variable or define a  pointer(considering array property).

I want to use it. How do i use this variable? `abc.array[0]` seems correct. Isn't it.

**Addition** I am not using any dynamic memory allocation then what is its significance ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [One element array in struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559558/one-element-array-in-struct)

Comment: In C99 better use [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member). In older standards of C, an array of dimension one was often used.

Comment: @GovindParmar thank you. Can you please tell me how can i use it. I am not doing any dynamic memory allocation

Comment: The answer linked by @GovindParmar contains an example how to call `malloc` for such a struct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably what is called the "struct hack". By allocating a large block of memory, the array becomes dynamic. The one element is just a placeholder to make it compile, in fact there will be many floats.

The dynamic array has to be the last element.

Use like this:

```
struct abc *ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct abc) + (N-1) * sizeof(float));
ptr->variable1 = N; /* usually store length somewhere in struct*/
```